# Ingress does not set IP-Adress in minikube 1.23 and Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ip-address, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I am learning some Kubernetes and am in the ingress section of this tutorial.
There I have had to change my config file for the ingress to the newer version of Kubernes. That starts also so far quite well, but unfortunately the ingress is not assigned my host IP.
The orginal file for the ingress looks like this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
```

My adjustment is the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 80
```

If I then look at the ingress with "get" I get the following result

```
 kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard  
NAME                CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
dashboard-ingress   <none>   dashboard.com             80      18m
```

and with describe comes out the following

```
kubectl describe ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard  
Name:             dashboard-ingress
Namespace:        kubernetes-dashboard
Address:          
Default backend:  kubernetes-dashboard:80 (172.17.0.6:9090)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  dashboard.com  
                 /   kubernetes-dashboard:80 (172.17.0.6:9090)
Annotations:     <none>
Events:          <none>
```

when i look at the logs from ingress pod, this is what catches my eye

```
8 main.go:101] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="dashboard-ingress/kubernetes-dashboard"
I0917 14:56:01.607654       8 store.go:361] "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="kubernetes-dashboard/dashboard-ingress" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"
E0917 14:56:11.341175       8 leaderelection.go:361] Failed to update lock: configmaps "ingress-controller-leader" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:ingress-nginx" cannot update resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-nginx"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Greetings niesel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug that has been reported and solved in minikube 1.23.1. You must just update minikube to 1.23.1 and ingress will work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly the problem. Now it works and I can continue learning. :)